# routeProvider not working correctly

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Im using angularJS to set where i want the page to go after i login, but if i only have this

```
function routeProviderFunction($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/default',{
    templateUrl: 'HTML/login.html',
    controller: funct2
});

$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/default'
});
}
```

My route provider works in the above code, but after i turn it into this

```
    function routeProviderFunction($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/default',{
    templateUrl: 'HTML/login.html',
    controller: funct2
});
$routeProvider.when('/adminMenu/:username', {
     templateUrl: 'HTML/adminMenu.html',
     controller: adminMenu
     });


$routeProvider.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/default'
});
}
```

My route provider ceases to work at all. Any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do like this:

```
$routeProvider
            .when('/default', {
                templateUrl: 'HTML/login.html',
                controller : 'funct2'
            }).when('/adminMenu/:username', {
                templateUrl: 'HTML/adminMenu.html',
                controller : 'adminMenu'
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo : '/default'
            });
```

Comment: thank you this worked, now new question. When i try to use the controller adminMenu i get a no adminMenu defined even though its defined with in the js files linked to adminMenu.html?

Comment: you need to import your controller js file in your index html page.
ex: I've got an index.html where I've an div container where I put my view with ng-view attribute, in this page I import every js I need, like the controllers

Comment: as in add it to the other scripts that are loaded?

Comment: because if i add it to the scripts area it still wont load

Answer (score 0):

Does the controller adminMenu exist in the global namespace? Press F12 and check the error console. Angular has quite decent error messages. Also worth noting that 'when' is chainable so you should be doing something like this route.when().when().otherwise();

Answer (score 0):

After looking @fabuloso answer, it clicked to me what I needed to fix my problem.

I had

```
pageApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'content/home.html',
            controller  : 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the directions page
        .when('/directions', {
            templateUrl : 'content/directions.html',
            controller  : 'directionsController'
        })

        // route for the giftCards page
        .when('/giftCards', {
            templateUrl : 'content/giftCards.html',
            controller  : 'giftCardsController'
        });

        // route for the giftCards page
        .when('/contactUs', {
            templateUrl : 'content/contactUs.html',
            controller  : 'contactUsController'
        });

});
```

when adding the last "contactUs" part, I noticed I had a semicolon after the giftCards route, which blows up everything.